# Shiny: Plotting a graph whose name contains an interactive input value

Tags: r, graph, shiny, plotly

In ShinyApp, I want to plot a graph whose name has an interactive input value. So in the ui.R side, the user chooses an input value from 0, 1 or 2. And in the server.R side, I want the App to plot a graph whose name is either pl0, pl1 or pl2. That is to say, if the user chooses 0 as an input value, the App plots a graph pl0, so does the same for pl1 for input 1, and for pl2 and input 2. I am using plotly library for plotting graphs.

I have tried print(), plot(), return(), but neither of them worked.
Any solution or advice would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Here is my ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Star Cluster Simulations"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for time
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "time",
                  label = "Select time to display a snapshot",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 2,
                  value = 0)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

And here is my server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

# load data
for(i in 0:2) {
  infile <- paste0("Data/c_0", i, "00.csv")
  a <- read.csv(infile)
  b <- assign(paste0("c_0", i, "00"), a)
  names(a) <- paste0("c_0", i, "00")
  pl <- plot_ly(b, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, color = ~id) %>%
    add_markers() %>%
    layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'x'),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'y'),
                        zaxis = list(title = 'z')))
  assign(paste0("pl", i), pl)
}

# shinyServer
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({

    # this doesn't work
    print(paste0("pl", input$time)) 

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this since your question isn't reproducible (i.e. doesn't include data), but one way to switch between text values (i.e. the values returned from Shiny inputs) and R objects is by making a reactive expression that uses the `switch` function. You can call the reactive expression (in the case below, `plot.data()`) inside `renderPlotly` (or any other render function) to switch between datasets.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  plot.data <- reactive({
    switch(paste0("pl", input$time),
           "pl0" = pl0,
           "pl1" = pl1,
           "pl2" = pl2)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    plot.data()
  })

})
```

Comment: this works perfectly as I desired. I didn't know about the switch function It's very convenient and computationally it's fast! Thank you very much!